# Python built-in heap (heapq): Odd behavior if inverted (max-heap)

Tags: python, heap, min-heap, max-heap

I'm trying to use the Python (2.0) built-in min-heap data structure from the heapq module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) to build a max-heap. To do that I simply use the negative of the numbers I need to push into my heap.

Using this (max-heap version):

```
import heapq
h=[]
for i in xrange(10):
    heapq.heappush(h,-i)
    print h
```

I get something which doesn't look correct:

```
[0]
[-1, 0]
[-2, 0, -1]
[-3, -2, -1, 0]
[-4, -3, -1, 0, -2]
[-5, -3, -4, 0, -2, -1]
[-6, -3, -5, 0, -2, -1, -4]
[-7, -6, -5, -3, -2, -1, -4, 0]
[-8, -7, -5, -6, -2, -1, -4, 0, -3]
[-9, -8, -5, -6, -7, -1, -4, 0, -3, -2]
```

The min-heap version instead looks fine:

```
import heapq
h=[]
for i in xrange(10):
    heapq.heappush(h,i)
    print h
```

As you can see:

```
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

What am I missing?

I've checked other SE questions/answers (e.g., [python topN max heap, use heapq or self implement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189540/python-topn-max-heap-use-heapq-or-self-implement/14189741#14189741), [What do I use for a max-heap implementation in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501457/what-do-i-use-for-a-max-heap-implementation-in-python/2501527#2501527), etc.) but they don't mention this issue.

Comment: You've posted the same code for both examples...

Comment: It's a heap, not a sorted list. Everything is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @user2357112 already mentioned, it is a min-heap. There is nothing wrong with the output. The difference between the 2 inputs is that, in the first scenario you enter the data in sorted fashion and in the second scenario, you input the data in reverse sorted fashion.

> the min-heap property: the value of each node is greater than or equal
>   to the value of its parent, with the minimum-value element at the
>   root.

Case 1 : Reverse Sorted Input = 10,9,8,7,6

```
         10
        [10]

         9
        /
      10
      [9,10]


        8
       / \
     10   9
     [8,10,9]


        7
       / \
      8   9
     /
    10
    [7, 8,9,10]

        6
       / \
      7   9
     / \
    10  8
    [6,7,9,10,8]
```

Case 2 : Sorted Input = 1,2,3,4,5

```
         1
        [1]

         1
        /
       2
      [1,2]


        1
       / \
      2   3
     [1,2,3]


        1
       / \
      2   3
     /
    4
    [1,2,3,4]

        1
       / \
      2   3
     / \
    4   5
    [1,2,3,4,5]
```

If you are interested in how the heap is built and how it balances after every input, go to the following url. You can insert one element at a time and see it in action. 
https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/JavascriptVisual/Heap.html

Comment: Many thanks for your answer Renuka. Your tree-graph visualization has been particularly useful, included the mentioned link with the interactive visualization. The website [https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/JavascriptVisual/Algorithms.html](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/JavascriptVisual/Algorithms.html) for various data structures is actually very well made.

Answer (score 2):

The invariant of a min-heap is that each node is less than either of its children; there is no implied ordering between the two children (and therefore, there can be many valid orderings of a given set of values; the only value that has an absolutely fixed position is the minimum one, at the root of the tree).  Note that this is true of your output:

```
                  ,------------------,
  ,---+---,   ,---|----------+---,   |
  |   V   V   |   |          V   V   V
[-9, -8, -5, -6, -7, -1, -4, 0, -3, -2]
      |   |   ^   ^   ^   ^
      `---|---+---'   |   |
          `-----------+---'
```

The fact that your other example ended up in completely sorted order is merely a coincidence, based on the different order in which items were inserted into the heap.